# Microsoft Azure AD Connect Provisioning Agent error 5

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, virtual-desktop

I am getting this error. How I going to solve this. Some configurations are disabled and inactive. Please help me. Thank you.

Also when connecting the Microsoft Azure Active Directory Connect Provisioning Agent Configuration. Its say that error. Please see images.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provisioning Agent cloud sync keeps track of the condition of your configuration and quarantines any unhealthy components. Whenever calls sent to the target system continually fail on invalid credentials.

To resolve this issue:

You can clear the quarantine and restart the provisioning job like below:

[image]

You can view additional details regarding the quarantine by selecting the status and the error code message also will display.

To restart provisioning job, ***click on your domain -> edit cloud sync configuration*** and -> **Restart sync**.

[image]

> **we encountered an unexpected error when registering the agent please try again**

When you deploy the cloud provisioning agent, you may receive an error message. Generally, the agent's unable to implement the PowerShell registration scripts is what causes this issue.

Try to change [PowerShell execution policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.3)  make sure local machine and user policy should be **`RemoteSigned`** or **`Undefined`**

If still error persists you can repair the cloud sync service account using below cmd:

- [Install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/cloud-sync/reference-powershell#install-the-aadcloudsynctools-powershell-module) AADCloudSyncTool **`Connect-AADCloudSyncTools`** , Enter credentials
- Run **`Repair-AADCloudSyncToolsAccount`**

Reference:

[Azure AD Cloud Sync Highlights and Deployment (misconfig.io)](https://misconfig.io/azure-ad-cloud-sync-highlights-and-deployment/)